# Can I propose a contest for my own "programming language"?

Tags: discussion, code-challenge

I have a custom CPU emulator, with 44 instructions (opcodes), and I would like to challenge you guys to code a better kernel for it (current one is a simple command interpreter with 3 commands: HELP, EXEC and QUIT). Can I?

Comment: I need 20 reputation to chat on "The Nineteenth Byte", should I post it at the Sandbox?

Comment: @WilliamFernandes Yeah. It will most like be removed here, so the sandbox is your best bet. Goodluck!

Comment: Sounds like fun if you can find a way to turn it into a challenge.

Comment: At least tell us what the opcodes are so we can start our answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure! That's sounds perfectly fine. You might want to post a draft in the sandbox for feedback, first.

You'll need a concise, but detailed description of what the program should do. And probably some example inputs and outputs.

And you'll also need an objective winning criterion. (Something better than 'better', like shortest or fastest)